# Updating an ID tag on scroll React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

You can find my project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/franchise-bg-effect-obd55

I am trying to match an array of CSS background ID tags (`bgArr`) to an array of each section (`destination.index`) in `afterLoad()`. So section 1 should have the ID of 'red', section 2 ID of 'blue', and section 3 ID of 'green'. On page load, section 1 has the correct ID tag of 'red'. When scrolling to section 2, in the console you will notice that `bgIndex` updates to the correct ID tag of 'blue' but the ID of the div on the page remains red. I'm not sure how to re-render the div with the updated ID tag.

Comment: can you post some code or image of what are you trying to achieve? the quality of the answer sometimes depends on the quality of the question. cheers :)

Comment: You can find the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/franchise-bg-effect-obd55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of this:

```
afterLoad(origin, destination, direction) {
  this.setState({
    isLeaving: false,
  });

  bgIndex = bgArr[destination.index];
}
```

you should do this:

```
afterLoad(origin, destination, direction) {
  bgIndex = bgArr[destination.index];

  this.setState({
    isLeaving: false,
  });
}
```

If you change `bgIndex` after the `setState` call, the rerender might have already finished before `bgIndex` is updated to its correct value.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/franchise-bg-effect-forked-cryyb?file=/src/index.js)